# What telephonyManager.getCellLocation() method return

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I use `telephonyManager.getCellLocation()`  and i get the result which is [-1,-1,0] but i can't  understand from the output.
 Is this any type of location code because i don't think that it is a kind of lat lang of any position.
advance thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can get locating the position using the LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER instead of LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER. The NETWORK_PROVIDER will resolve on the GSM or wifi, which ever available. Obviously with wifi off, GSM will be used. Keep in mind that using the cell network is accurate to basically 500m.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html has some really great information and sample code.

After you get done with most of the code in OnCreate(), add this:

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
  makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
 };

  // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

You could also have your activity implement the LocationListener class and thus implement onLocationChanged() in your activity.
or you can use [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) tutorial to get lat and lang.

Comment: i know about location manager dear but what is the mean of that output from telephonyManager.getCellLocation() have u aware about telephonyManager class. i m talking abt that class's method

Comment: The getCellLocation method is used to get the Cell Location of the device. This method returns an instance of GsmCellLocation class. The getCid() and getLac() methods of this class can used to retrieve the Cell ID and LAC of the device. This method requires the permission ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. Following code snippet shows how to retrieve the Cell ID and LAC.

TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
GsmCellLocation loc = (GsmCellLocation) tm.getCellLocation();

int cellid = loc.getCid();
int lac = loc.getLac();

Comment: himani i m talking about my output have u know what is the mean of that output [-1,-1,0]

Comment: Are you testing that on emulator or on real device?

Comment: It returns ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and/or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION that is of your device. TelephonyManager.getCellLocation() will return only GSM/UMTS or CDMA cells. It it limited to one cell, the one with which the device is currently registered. your code will only be running on GSM/UMTS or CDMA devices, and if you are only interested in the cell with which the device is currently registered.