# android :how to localise only with wifi or mobile network by code without using popup security menu

Tags: android, localization, gps, wifi

j know that since 4.0 it s impossible to trigger programmatically gps
but besides that there are three possibilities to localise

1) gps and wifi and mobile network (all together)

2) only wifi and mobile network

3) only gps

is there some possible code to get through the second one

so let's be clear j don't want to trigger wifi. that i know

j want to trigger localisation by whatever wifi (and)or mobile network without using gps

j tried to implement  some object like skyhook' WPSPeriodicLocationCallback or WPSLocationCallback but 
it doesn 't work without triggering the official android security menu

so what j want is getting through the positionning system only with wifi or internet connection and that by code

avast antitheft does that giving back some information with more or less accuracy .

i would like to reproduce the same

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get locating the position using the LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER instead of LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER. The NETWORK_PROVIDER will resolve on the GSM or wifi, which ever available. Obviously with wifi off, GSM will be used. Keep in mind that using the cell network is accurate to basically 500m.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html has some really great information and sample code.

After you get done with most of the code in OnCreate(), add this:

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
  makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
 };

  // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

You could also have your activity implement the LocationListener class and thus implement onLocationChanged() in your activity or you can use [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) tutorial to get lat and lang.

Copypasted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22559794/4279419).

Comment: all is working fine except that locationlistener class give me position info only after  triggering the official android security menu

Comment: for being brief i want not to call "Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);" all things must be done silently like antitheft does